# How to break {} naturally when I press Enter in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, hotkeys

I have a habit when writing code:

If I want to write a code block inside a `{}`, I will type `{}` first, then move the cursor into between `{` and `}`, press `Enter` and write my code.

In IntelliJ IDE, after I press `Enter`, IDE auto break and format for `{}` for me to write code (see this image with green arrow).

With Netbeans, it doesn't work like that (see the image with red screen).

[image]

My question is how to setting Netbeans IDE to work like IntelliJ to convenient for me to write code.

Comment: Voting to close this as being off topic.

Comment: I don't know to display image directly in my post, just attach a hyperlink. Sorry for my bad. @Edwin

Comment: Edited your post to show up the image, just need to accept the edit proposal. Stack overflow is here for programming/code questions tho, you may want to check another stack !

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet Questions regarding IDEs are on-topic. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic _software tools commonly used by programmers_

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Why off-topic? Questions regarding _software tools commonly used by programmers_ are on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ModusTollens My bad, seen a few post getting closed on that kind of topics, should have searched a bit more ! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

I have never written in NetBeans before. But I can understand you - it is so inconvenient and painful.

I have been going through all the combinations and haven't found the one needed.

The options that might repeat this behaviour somehow include:

1. Typing a <kbd>{</kbd> and pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd>. Code completion will automatically add the second brace and put you in the right place.
2. Using the combination <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Then I figured out that we can write a macro:

```
split-line insert-break
```

[image]

The result:

[image]

Unfortunately, the macro is contextless. We can't write the condition *"if the caret is between braces do our action otherwise, do the standard one"*. So, it can be assigned to another hotkey (not <kbd>enter</kbd>) to make <kbd>enter</kbd> work correctly in its cases.

Comment: That option 1 works fine for me. Type first { and press Enter, Code completion will automatically add the second }. Thanks for your help @Andrew